# jQuery Form Plugin not updating progress bar, showing [jquery.form] state = uninitialized

Tags: jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

I am trying to show the progress of an upload handled by the jQuery Form Plugin, as they demonstrate on their site. No matter what I seem to try, I cannot get the percentage of the upload progress to display and Firebug is showing `[jquery.form] state = uninitialized` in the console as the file uploads. Right as the upload finishes, Firebug shows `[jquery.form] state = loading
jquery.form.js (line 904)
[jquery.form] isXml=false`

Here is my Javascript. The back-end is using class.upload.php, www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm, and returns JSON on completion.

```
$("#apparatusPhotoUpload").ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
        //Do things such as disable upload button, switch to default preview image
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var progress = percentComplete;
        $("#uploadProgress").html(progress);
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        //Fire a couple of functions that alter data in the DOM
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where you able to find a solution? I have a similar problem with jquery.form plugin...

Comment: I think I finally gave up on this. When I wade out of the project I'm working on right now, I'll fiddle with it again and post a solution, if I find one.

Comment: Try this..
Specify Form method in the ajax form fix this problem for me..
(you may forget to add method in HTML form)

Comment: the exact problem I am facing...form automatically reload while uploading. only uploadProgress event is not working..

Answer (score 1):

*GitHub solution:* [never ending loop with blank file input (patch included)](https://github.com/malsup/form/issues/113)

As per [malsup](https://github.com/malsup) comment

```
Added proposed fix to v2.91.
```

Download [jQuery.form.js version 3.50](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/malsup/form/master/jquery.form.js)

Problem solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the new plugin fixed some related bugs. I was having a similar problem but I was able to make it work by installing the latest version of the [jQuery Form Plugin](https://github.com/malsup/form/) (version: 3.26.0-2013.01.28) and using something like this (adapted to your example) in my javascript:

```
$("#apparatusPhotoUpload").ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit: function() {
        //Do things such as disable upload button
        var progress_bar = $('<div class="progress"><div class="bar" style="width:0;"></div></div>');
        progress_bar.appendTo("#apparatusPhotoUpload");
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        $('.bar').width(percentVal);
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, form) {
        //Fire a couple of functions that alter data in the DOM to show responseText
}
```